# Draw the skybox over specific game objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering

I want to know if there is a easy way to have the skybox draw over a gameObject, kind of like if the block is transparent but it also hides everything behind it. I'm a bit new to Unity so I don't know how to script shaders but I am pretty good at shader graphs. Anyone have any solutions?

Comment: How many gameobjects are yoou planning to hide behind the block? If it's not too many you could look into a stencil shader. You'd attach a custom shader to each object you want hidden, which will cull any drawing while behind the object.

Comment: Well, a few, but maybe not too many, I'll try it out, but incase that doesn't work, only other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: There are defiantly other ways of accomplishing this, but this would be my first guess. You could also look into a shader which samples the skybox given the camera position.